# how to fix CSS transition for a background-image on hover?

Tags: css, html, css-transitions, navbar

Am working in a School project to make an e-commerce website, I want to make a CSS transition on the navbar blocks ( the lis inside the ul ) like when I hover on a block the background-image of that block shows up, but it seems the transition doesn't work and only the normal instant hover happens.

this is my code showing only one block of the navbar which is the *catalogue*:

```css
#catalogue {
  -o-transition-property: all;
  -o-transition-duration: 2s;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -o-transition-delay: 2s;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#catalogue:hover {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 70px;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(f1.png);
  background-size: 125px 70px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li id="home"><a>Home</a></li>
    <li id="catalogue"><a>Catalogue</a></li>
    <li id="news"><a>News&Trends </a></li>
    <li id="contact"><a>Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: replace `margin-left` with `padding-left`. `margin` will move your container, so you will see glitches when container moves out of your mouse pointer.

Comment: Also, remove the CSS prefix '-o-'. Browsers no more need prefix for transitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use opera (`-o-`) prefixes on your transition properties. CSS transitions do not require prefixes anymore: http://shouldiprefix.com/#transitions

Instead of transitions, for the background effect, you should use CSS animations - because as of today it isn't possible to apply transitions to background propreties.

```
li {
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out 2s;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

li:hover {
  margin-left: 70px;
  position: relative;
  background-size: 125px 70px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 600;
  animation: backgroundIMG 2s ease-in-out 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes backgroundIMG {
  100% { background-image: url(http://www.rayesdesign.com/glitters/blue/blue016.gif); }
}
```

See it running here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lkawnpg6/1/

Ps. I've changed the image for testing.

Comment: More info on CSS animations: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation

Comment: I did what you mentioned, I saw a change but there's no animation and incorrect delay ( if I put delay to ".5s" I still wait more than "2s" )

Comment: It works in the fiddle, even with '.5s', see here: https://jsfiddle.net/ew6b2tsz/ - There must be something else somewhere in your code affecting it. If you can copy / paste the corresponding code blocks to your nav element in a fiddle and link it, it'd be easier to say.

Comment: Thank you so much , it worked . I toyed with the opacity in the animation and had it done !

Answer (score 1):

You can't transition a background-image like that.

You can try adding an extra div on top with the background (or a pseudo element :before or :after) and then transition it's opacity.

Normally you would transition a background-color like below

```css
.box {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.box:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this helps.

```
#YourDIV {
    background-image: url(Yourimage.jpg) no-repeat;
}

#YourDIV:hover {
  background-image: url(Yourimage.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 150%;
}
```